# Micronaut unauthorized request with redirect problem

Tags: java, security, micronaut

I have a problem with micronaut-security during unauthorized requests.

For example: I logged out and try to get secured endpoint. Now I receive response with status 401 and that is all, but I would like to redirect user to login page.

My security properties are below:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8080
  views:
    folder: views
    thymeleaf:
      enabled: true
      suffix: .html
      template-mode: html
  security:
    enabled: true
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: true
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        bearer:
          enabled: false
        cookie:
          enabled: true
          login-success-target-url: /welcome
          login-failure-target-url: /failure
          logout-target-url: /login
          cookie-name: MY-NAME
```

What do you think about it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use **micronaut-security-session** instead of **micronaut-security-jwt**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
   <artifactId>micronaut-security-session</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and add property **micronaut.security.session.unauthorized-target-url**